# In Google Sheets, how to find cells value greater than or less than between 4 different values and add a value that is for which they fall into?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 50 values in a column and am want to automatically find which 4 tiers of numbers they are in-between and those tiers result in an additional number to add to the original in a different column.

Tiers are 0-149, 150-249, 250-399, 400-infinity and their the values they add to the original are 20, 50, 100, 175.

Is there a formula or script or a term for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function noTiersPlease() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg1=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var rg2=sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  var vB=rg2.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]>=0 && vA[i][0]<=149) {
      vB[i][0]=vA[i][0] + 20;
    }else if(vA[i][0]>=150 && vA[i][0]<=249) {
      vB[i][0]=vA[i][0] + 50;
    }else if(vA[i][0]>=250 && vA[i][0]<=399) {
      vB[i][0]=vA[i][0] + 100;
    }else if(vA[i][0]>=400) {
      vB[i][0]=vA[i][0] + 175;
    }
  }
  rg2.setValues(vB);
}
```

My Spreadsheet:

[image]